# How to bind 'Attachment' table to 'PrivateMessage' and 'Post' tables

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have 3 tables `PrivateMessage`, `Post` and `Attachment`. Simplified structure below:

```
PrivateMessage
--------------
 - ID (Primary Key)
 - PMContent

Post (means topic's/thread's post)
--------------
 - ID (Primary Key)
 - PostContent

Attachment
--------------
 - ID (Primary Key)
 - FileName
 - Bytes
 - ContentType
```

`Post` must be a distinct table, so it's not allowed to combine `PrivateMessage` and `Post` into one table. `Attachment` table should store information about user's attachments from private messages and topic posts. How to design `Attachment` table correctly?

Is this correct below?

```
Attachment
--------------
- ID (PK)
- PostID (FK and allow nulls)
- PrivateMessageID (FK and allow nulls)
- FileName
- Bytes
- ContentType
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your approach would work, I would opt for one of the following solutions:

1. Create linking tables `PrivateMessageAttachment` and `PostAttachment` where you would keep references to the primary tables using FKs(`id | private_message_id | attachment_id`).

This way you would have the following entities: `PrivateMessage`, `Post`, `Attachment`, `PrivateMessageAttachment`, `PostAttachment`.

2. Create separate attachment tables, for both entities, simply referencing them with one-to-many relationships.

This way you would end up the following entities: `PrivateMessage`, `Post`, `PrivateMessageAttachment`, `PostAttachment`.

Comment: I don't actually think that a 'right' answer really exists here, as I finally came to a conclusion that it all depends on a project. And in my project (it was my personal and small project) I simply separated attachment tables like you suggested in second solution.

Comment: Totally agree! It depends heavily on the project, but I feel these two approaches cover most of the use-cases.